# How do I remove nullpointerexception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, video-streaming, media-player, jmf

I am trying to play a video using jmf. After working hard for hours literally removing all errors and exceptions, Here I am getting a null pointer exception. Here I figured out after looking on NullPointerException, this should be due to incorrect declaration of Player mediaPlayer where it is not initialised to anything.

Another problem with directly initialising it to what values I am giving it later is, I have to catch the exceptions too, then it says player might not be declared.

How do I declare `mediaURL` and `Player` so that this `nullpointerexception` is removed and I can play this video.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.media.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;


    public class mediaPlayer extends JFrame
    {

    URL mediaURL;
    Player mediaPlayer;
        public mediaPlayer()
        {   
            JFrame f = new JFrame("new");
            f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            f.setSize(500,300);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            //file you want to play
            try{
            String name = "file:///"+new File("output.mp4").getAbsolutePath();
                mediaURL = new URL(name);
            }catch (MalformedURLException ex){}
            //create the media player with the media url
            try{
                mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mediaURL);
            }catch(IOException ex){} catch(NoPlayerException ex){} catch(CannotRealizeException ex){}
            //get components for video and playback controls
            Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
            Component controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();
            add(video,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(controls,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            f.setVisible(true);

        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            new mediaPlayer();
        }
    }
```

## **Update2**

```
javax.media.NotRealizedError: Cannot get visual component on an unrealized playe
r
        at com.sun.media.BasicPlayer.getVisualComponent(BasicPlayer.java:491)
        at com.sun.media.MediaPlayer.getVisualComponent(MediaPlayer.java:48)
        at mediaPlayer.<init>(mediaPlayer.java:29)
        at mediaPlayer.main(mediaPlayer.java:38)
Exception in thread "main" javax.media.NotRealizedError: Cannot get visual compo
nent on an unrealized player
        at com.sun.media.BasicPlayer.getVisualComponent(BasicPlayer.java:491)
        at com.sun.media.MediaPlayer.getVisualComponent(MediaPlayer.java:48)
        at mediaPlayer.<init>(mediaPlayer.java:29)
        at mediaPlayer.main(mediaPlayer.java:38)
```

Please help me in playing this video, removing this `nullpointer exception`. Thanks a lot to everyone who puts any effort on my problem:).

Comment: Player is an interface, try instantiating like this `Player mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Player.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.media.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;


    public class mediaPlayer extends JFrame
    {
        public mediaPlayer()
        {   
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Video Demo");
            f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            f.setSize(500,300);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            //file you want to play
            try{
                String name = "file:///"+new File("output.mp4").getAbsolutePath();
                URL mediaURL = new URL(name);
                Player mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mediaURL);
            //get components for video and playback controls
            Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
            Component controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();
            f.add(video,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            f.add(controls,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            f.setVisible(true);

        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            new mediaPlayer();
        }
    }
```

Credits-Andrew Thompson.

Comment: This works but now it gives a new exceptions, I am editing the question please see.

Answer (score 0):

Player is an interface so you cannot make its object. Instead use Manager.createPlayer(source) method to get your working. 
Here is the link , [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/opt-pkgs/api/jsr927/javax/media/Manager.html#createPlayer%28javax.media.protocol.DataSource%29)

Comment: Use MediaLocator media=new MediaLocator(String file path)
and then player=Manager.createPlayer(media);

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [JMF 2.1.1 - Supported Formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html) page, you'll notice a distinct lack of mention for MP4.  Theoretically, fixing the problem as as 'simple' as obtaining a Service Provider Interface for MP4 files, and adding it to the run-time class-path.

The bottom line is that if this project is for playing a limited group of formats that are either inbuilt, or for which we can provide an SPI, it should be fine.  OTOH JMF is *not* suitable as a 'general purpose player'.  It is too old & supports too few formats.

Comment: I have also tried `.mov` and `.avi` formats. But they too show the same exceptions.

Comment: Try some of the MOV & MPEG files at my 'JMF friendly' [media files page](http://pscode.org/media/#video).  Note that the file extension is not all there is to it.  Even an AVI/MOV/MPEG can be encoded different ways, JMF supports some encoding types, but not others.  It would also help if you let me know which of the above two situations you need to use JMF for 1) using files encoded by you.  2) As a general purpose player.  Which is it?

Comment: Files encoded by me. And I will be using a fixed format not any other. The player would not at all be general-purpose. Just one file has to be played. @AndrewThompson

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  Let me know how you go with the media files at my site.

Comment: Thanks for being patient. But the video on your site too shows the exceptions, I will add them as update2 in the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34292/discussion-between-jeez-and-andrew-thompson)

Comment: Oh I put some comments there. Should I put them here?

Comment: Well you have helped a lot here. But the answer to this question is in the above answer. Not sure which to accept?

Comment: Eh.. (shrugs)  I think it would be more *accurate* to choose the answer of Optimus.  Go for it.

Comment: Okay. but I want to give the link to new question to you too. Will give it here. Please check that later.

Comment: Please check [the new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899557/what-type-of-avi-video-jmf-plays)