# What type of .avi video jmf plays?

Tags: java, video-streaming, media-player, jmf, avi

After struggling through exceptions in using jmf, on [How do I remove nullpointerexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897647/how-do-i-remove-nullpointerexception/).  I am able to now play my video, but only the .mov file [here at this website](http://pscode.org/media/#video).

But I am creating my video file using `ffmpeg` using images and `.wav` audio files.

I can create it in any format, `.avi`, `.mov`, `.mp4`, but what is important is I should be able to play it in my player, which I built using JMF.

Currently, I am getting this error,

```
Unable to handle format: FMP4, 1366x768, FrameRate=30.0, Length=3147264 0 extra bytes
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
        at mediaPlayer.<init>(mediaPlayer.java:31)
        at mediaPlayer.main(mediaPlayer.java:38)
```

The exceptions here are not the problem, since the player works fine with `lunarphases.mov` [on that site](http://pscode.org/media/#video).

**The problem is**

How do I encode the video so that my jmf media player can play it and handle the format?

Thanks for all your help and I really appreciate all your efforts you would put on this problem for me.  :)

Comment: I really don't know how to help on this one..  Sorry.   :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson How did you encode the videos [on your site](http://pscode.org/media/#video)

Comment: JpegImagesToMovie (example source of the JMF).  Note that I did not add sound to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar project where I used `jmf` to play video file.  I just used the `.mov` file. So I can suggest you about .mov. You may convert it later to .avi again.

Here is what you can do to play your .avi video in jmf, As far as I guess, this would work for all type of .avi videos. Your concern is to have a good quality video, it will give you a good quality video.

Here's the trick,

You first encode the video, whatever way you want to do it. You can set the bitrate, framerate everything the way you want to, the way you want to.

Try running the video with jmf, it may not run due to [limited support](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html) of formats by jmf. Then encode it according to [this site](http://jeshua.me/blog/EncodingvideowithffmpegforJMF).

The same code would now run the video in `jmf` video player without any problem.

The same is what Robadob pointed too in the above answer,

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec mjpeg -acodec pcm_s16be -ac 2 -y output.mov
```

Yes, it gave me a terrible quality video, so encode it by giving a different bit rate,

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec mjpeg -acodec pcm_s16be -ac 2 -y -b:v 5000k output.mov
```

This would give you a better quality `.mov` video.

Hope this helps:).

Comment: Looks like sometimes this fails too.

Comment: In what way? Isn't jmf playing the video?

Comment: No, qualitywise actually. Let me try more. I am unaccepting your answer for now.:(

Comment: Have you seen Andrew's comment on the question. The required format can be created by JpegImagesToMovie.

Comment: There seems to be a way but let me see if that works. Will try to tell you if possible by tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html

avi is a container, it can hold video encoded in various different methods. Check this list for the formats which JMF can and can't decode.

According to;
http://jeshua.me/blog/EncodingvideowithffmpegforJMF

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vcodec mjpeg -acodec pcm_s16be -ac 2 -y ouput.mov
```

Should work.

Comment: How do I encode my video into one of those formats is the problem Robadob.

Comment: Updated above after a little googling.

Comment: You could try using the Jffmpeg wrapper, I think it extends JMF to support decoders that ffmpeg supports.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jffmpeg

Comment: Even this doesn't work when i just add framerate, or keep size 1366*768.